# Plone Dynamic views Example doesn't work

Tags: python, dynamic, view, plone

I have tried create a Dynamic views in my first plone 4.3 instance. It doesn't work for me, although I have copied everything from the example. Have you any ideas, what's wrong with my code?

Thanks, Shan

Example from plone:
http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/dynamic_views.html

1. I have added listlessview in my buildout.cfg, rebuild plone

   eggs =
           ...
           listlessview
2. Register a dynamic view menu item with the corresponding view in configure.zcml
3. Updated profiles/default/types/Folder.xml

```
<object name="Folder"
    xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
    i18n:domain="plone"
    meta_type="Factory-based Type Information with dynamic views" >
    <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
        <!-- We retrofit these new views for Folders in portal_types info -->
        <element value="product_listing"/>
    </property>
</object>
```

Comment: Have you also added the corresponding `zcml` entry for your egg into your `buildout.cfg`, and also create a `<genericsetup:registerProfile...>` entry into your `configure.zcml`? For the dynamic view to work you need to be able to install your package via Site Setup > Add-ons which should enable things defined in generic setup related profiles.

Comment: I never user `listless`but it seems done for Dexterity based content types.
Are you using it on a Dexterity or Archetypes?

Comment: If you want to debug it step by step, `/url/to/folder/@@product_listing` will work even if you don't have the `Folder.xml` right and don't have the `browser:menuItem` right. (Are you maybe getting mixed up with the names by following the page and an example product that defines a different view?)

Comment: thanks for your answers. i have called /url/to/folder/@@product_listing.  but i got 404.